# How to create multiselect(dynamic selection of columns) dashboard in spotfire using iron python

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have used the below code to create a Dynamic selection dashboard, But this is giving me duplicate records on selecting individual columns. Is there a way to avoid duplicates?

Code:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot, VisualContent
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass

#multiselect doc prop control
multiSelectColumnsPropertyControl = "select" 

#reference to the data table
dataTable = Document.Data.Tables.DefaultTableReference   

# 1 Create a table if not there already
tablePlotVisual = None
updateTablePlot = False
defaultTableTitle=dataTable.Name

# 1.1 check if tablePlot already exist (based on name)
for v in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals: 
   tablePlotVisual = v
   updateTablePlot = v.Title == defaultTableTitle
   if v.Title == defaultTableTitle: break

# 2.1 If no tablePlot found, create a new one
if not updateTablePlot:
    tablePlotVisual = Application.Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals.AddNew[TablePlot]()
    tablePlotVisual.Data.DataTableReference = dataTable
    tablePlotVisual.Title = "${DataTable.DisplayName}"
    tablePlotVisual.Legend.Visible= False
else:
    tablePlotVisual=tablePlotVisual.As[VisualContent]()

# 2 Adds columns to a Data Table based on a document property. 

# 2.1 Remove all columns
cols = tablePlotVisual.Data.DataTableReference.Columns
tablePlotVisual.TableColumns.Clear()

# 2.2 get document property
selection = Document.Data.Properties.GetProperty(DataPropertyClass.Document, multiSelectColumnsPropertyControl).Value

# 2.3 Parse columns from selection and add to tablePlotVisual
for property in selection:
   for col in property.split(","): tablePlotVisual.TableColumns.Add(cols[str(col)])
```

**For Example:**
**input:**

```
empid  empname emp_loc  dept
101    aaa     chennai  IT
102    bbb     Delhi    HR
103    ccc     Delhi    HR
104    ddd     Mumbai   IT
```

**Ouput:** If emp_loc and dept are selected, the code is giving

```
emp_loc dept
Chennai IT
Delhi   HR
Delhi   HR
Mumbai  IT
```

**Expected Output:** But I need,

```
emp_loc  dept
Chennai  IT
Delhi    HR
Mumbai   IT
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you want to do? At this point, your code is removing columns from the original table and creating another display (also with the original data table with columns removed - but this does not change when changing 'select'). My guess is that you want to produce a new visualization of the original data table, with only the distinct values of the selected columns. But then you lose the information about the value count?

Comment: Yes, I want to produce a new visualization of the original data table, with only the distinct values of the selected columns.. But now i'm getting with duplicates. Also I tried using cross table instead of normal table, but it dint work

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution would be to create a pivot table, with the selected columns as row identifiers. This would give you the unique values.

Using these as starting point:

https://community.tibco.com/questions/remove-duplicate-rows-table-visualization

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-add-data-table-pivot-transformation-using-ironpython-tibco-spotfire

Try this script (based on your assumptions that the table in question is the default table and the default title of a table visual is the table name):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot, VisualContent
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataFlowBuilder, DataColumnSignature, DataType, DataSourcePromptMode
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Transformations import PivotTransformation
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import DataTableDataSource

#NEW function
#if table with name tablename exists, return it, otherwise return None
def findTable(tablename):
    try:
        return Document.Data.Tables[tablename]
    except:
        return None


#multiselect doc prop control
multiSelectColumnsPropertyControl = "select" 
#get document property
selection = Document.Data.Properties.GetProperty(DataPropertyClass.Document, multiSelectColumnsPropertyControl).Value


#reference to the data table
dataTable = Document.Data.Tables.DefaultTableReference  
defaultTableTitle=dataTable.Name
 
#NEW:pivot table name
pivotTableName ='newpivot'

#NEW: create or update a pivot table using as identifiers the selected columns 
ds = DataTableDataSource(dataTable)
ds.IsPromptingAllowed = False
ds.ReuseSettingsWithoutPrompting = True
dfb = DataFlowBuilder(ds, Application.ImportContext)

pivot = PivotTransformation()
list = List[DataColumnSignature]()
list.Clear()

#add selected columns as identifiers
for property in selection:  
    col = dataTable.Columns[property]
    list.Add(DataColumnSignature(col))
pivot.IdentityColumns = list

dfb.AddTransformation(pivot)
pivotContent = dfb.Build()

#if pivot table exists, replace its content, otherwise create a new one
pivotHandle = findTable(pivotTableName)
if (pivotHandle is not None):
    pivotHandle.ReplaceData(pivotContent) #update
else:
    Document.Data.Tables.Add(pivotTableName,pivotContent) #create
    pivotHandle = findTable(pivotTableName) #refresh handle
    

    
#create a table VISUAL if not there already
tablePlotVisual = None

#check if tablePlot already exist (based on name)
for v in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals: 
   if v.Title == defaultTableTitle:
        tablePlotVisual = v
        break

#if no tablePlot found, create a new one
if tablePlotVisual is None:
    tablePlotVisual = Application.Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals.AddNew[TablePlot]()
    tablePlotVisual.Data.DataTableReference = pivotHandle  #content of pivot table
    tablePlotVisual.Title = defaultTableTitle #title of original table
    tablePlotVisual.Legend.Visible= False
else:
    tablePlotVisual=tablePlotVisual.As[VisualContent]()

#make sure to add all selected columns to the visual
tablePlotVisual.TableColumns.Clear()
for property in selection:
    tablePlotVisual.TableColumns.Add(pivotHandle.Columns.Item[property])
```